# Can I have a body and a file in the Form-Data of a http request

Tags: http, go, https, rest

I'm working in a Go Lang REST API repo.

I'm wanting to build an endpoint that will take in a file (as part of the form-data, so I suppose I'll use `request.FormFile('my-file-key')`). This endpoint should also take in a body of a JSON model (which i suppose would be decoded with something like this:

```
var myData model.MyModel
json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&myData)
```

But I'm running into a lot of issues. Is it even possible to send both a body and a file in the form-data with a http request?

If I try to send both I get errors from `FormFile` saying that it can't find the file of the key name (but if I send the exact same request without a body, this error doesn't happen). I guessing it's having trouble decoding the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a multipart request. One part can be JSON data, and the other part the file data.

If you're using a Go client to prepare the request, you need to use the `mime/multipart` package to create a `Writer`, then use `CreatePart` to create the JSON part, then the file part, and submit the request to the server.

On the decoding side: since the body is JSON you cannot parse it as a form. You have to use a `multipart.Reader` to read from the body after you parse the headers. Again, from that reader you get a `Part`, and read the data from that part. You'll get two parts, one for the JSON data and one for the file data.